# Function specialization: Which is the declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Given:

```
template<class T>
struct test {

    void foo(int b);

    void testFunc( int a )
    {
    }

};

void test::foo(int b)
{

}


template<>
void test<float>::testFunc( int a )
{

}

void someFunction()
{
}
```

We know that "`test::foo`" has a declaration in the test class, and a definition outside the class definition.
We also know that "`someFunction`" has a declaration which is also its definition.
In like manner "`test::testFunc`" (non-specialized), has a declaration which is also its definition.
Is the specialization function "`test<float>::testFunc`" said to be declared with the declaration of "`testFunc`" inside of class "test" and defined separately, or is its declaration also the definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit specialization in your example is a declaration that is also a definition.  You could also declare it separately:

```
template<>
void test<float>::testFunc( int a );
```

and if the function was used, the linker would expect it to be defined somewhere.

The declaration inside the class is the declaration and definition of the member function template.

BTW, foo should be defined like this:

```
template <class T>
void test<T>::foo(int b)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the useful answer @Vaughn provided.

In the template definition of `test`, you have a non-defining member function declaration and also a defining member function declaration. But that function definition and declaration is associated with the surrounding template `test<T>`, and not with the class `test<float>` that will eventually be instantiated from it!

If you implicitly instantiate `test<float>` from that template, for example by using the `::`-operator (scope) on it, or by creating a variable definition having that type and so on, then *declarations* but *not necessarily* the definitions of *all* members are *also* implicitly instantiated. All of them are associated with and members of `test<float>`.

So when you write your explicit specialization for `test<float>::testFunc`, because you used `::` to look into the class `test<float>`, that class is being implicitly instantiated and with it all its member declarations.

The *definition* of `test<float>::testFunc` is only instantiated when it is required (for example when you call it).

The explicit specialization you declared then *redeclares* the member function that was previously implicitly instantiated and provides a definition that *is* associated with `test<float>`. It is a real function and cannot be safely defined in a header unless it is marked `inline` - otherwise you risk "defined more than once" errors when you include its header multiple timrs.

To summarize what declarations and definitions exist for `testFunc` and where they come from:

- By your template definition:

  - `test<T>::testFunc(int);`
  - `test<T>::testFunc(int) { }`
- Generated specialization by the compiler from `test<T>::testFunc(int);`

  - `test<float>::testFunc(int);`
- Explicit specialization by you of `test<T>::testFunc(int);`

  - `test<float>::testFunc(int);`
  - `test<float>::testFunc(int) { }`

In particular, there is no generated definition of `test<float>::testFunc`. If there was, then your code would be ill-formed, without diagnostics required, because the generated definition would interfere with your explicit specialization that provided a definition for the same function. But such a thing can only happen if you cause its instantiation before explicitly specializing it. So if you move the explicit specialization definition into a `.cpp` file (if you don't want to make it `inline`), put an explicit specialization *declaration*, like @Vaughn demonstrated, into the header.